# python memory error when loading MNIST.pkl.gz

Tags: python, python-2.7, out-of-memory, mnist

I am new to Python and I have downloaded the code DBN.py but there is a problem:when I was trying to load the dataset MNIST.pkl.gz.there is always an meomory error..
my code is very simple:

```
import cPickle, gzip, numpy
# Load the dataset
f = gzip.open('C:\Users\MAC\Desktop\mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

and the error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-17-528eea6bbfdd>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/MAC/Documents/Python Scripts/untitled0.py',  wdir='C:/Users/MAC/Documents/Python Scripts')

File "C:\Users\MAC\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\MAC\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/Users/MAC/Documents/Python Scripts/untitled0.py", line 19, in <module>
train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)

File "C:\Users\MAC\Anaconda\lib\gzip.py", line 268, in read
self._read(readsize)

File "C:\Users\MAC\Anaconda\lib\gzip.py", line 320, in _read
self._add_read_data( uncompress )

File "C:\Users\MAC\Anaconda\lib\gzip.py", line 338, in _add_read_data
self.extrabuf = self.extrabuf[offset:] + data

MemoryError
```

I really have no idea,is it because the memory of my computer is too small? it is on windows 7,32 bits

Comment: How large is the `mnist.pkl.gz`? In * MB*  that is.

Comment: eww....I just checked.it's 15.4MB

Comment: The problem is most likely not in the pickle state, but in the script you're using to run your other script. Do you have a loop that iterates over many files?

Comment: I just found out  if I delete the third line of the code which is: "train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)",the error will no longer be existed.is it  because this line involves something complicated...sorry I am really new to this..

Comment: sorry but I don't think I have this kind of loop...the code of four lines is all I wrote...

Comment: Chris, you're using some sort of library or application to start your script, called `spyder`?

Comment: yes..I am using spyder

Comment: is there any problem with spyder?

Comment: Chris, probably not but I have no experience with it and your code is working as intended. Could you perhaps upload the file you're decoding (unless it contains private information)? Or perhaps run the code outside of Spyder, just save your few lines as a script and run `python myscript.py` manually. It's easier to debug without any additional abstraction layers.

Comment: Thank you very much..I think Spyder is exactly the problem..I just run the code on Python Notebook and everything worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem to be Spyder in this case.
As to why, I have no idea but either the process isn't allowed to allocate enugh memory outside of it's own script or it simply gets stuck in a loop some how.

Try running your code without Spyder by pasting your code into `myscript.py` for instance and open a `terminal` and navigate to the folder where you saved your script and run `python myscript.py` and see if that works or gives the same output.

This is based on a conversation in the comments above.